# Mismatch Error Filter.Me Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been busy creating a database and I am using combo boxes to filter several lists of data. I used the following code:

```
Private Sub cbobedrijf_AfterUpdate()
Me.Filter = "Bedrijf_klant = '" & Me.cbobedrijf & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Which worked perfectly for about four forms and 10 combo boxes in total. When I tried to use this code on my last form I received the following error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

I am not able to solve this problem and I do not understand why this error appears, because I copied->pasted the code and changed it into:

```
Private Sub cbobedrijf_AfterUpdate() 
Me.Filter = "bedrijf_project = '"& Me.cbobedrijf & "'" 
Me.FilterOn = True 
End Sub
```

The same I did for all the other combo boxes.

Comment: What is Me.cbobedrijf ? try doing cstr(Me.cbobedrijf) or int(Me.cbobedrijf) depending on what it's supposed to be

Comment: Thank you for your response, Me.cbobedrijf is the combo box which I want to use to filter the collum of bedrijf_project. I tried doing cstr(Me.cobobedrijf) and (Me.cbobedrijf), but I ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cbobedrijf_AfterUpdate() 
    Debug.Print Me.FilterOn, "bedrijf_project = '" & Me.cbobedrijf & "'" 
    Me.Filter = "bedrijf_project = '"& Me.cbobedrijf & "'" 
    Me.FilterOn = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, project is set as a normal text. Even though I tried to use this code, but I ended up with the same error.

Comment: If so, your original code has to work. Something else is going on.

Comment: The debugger stops first on the Me.FilterOn = True line and secondly on the previous line. Does this mean something?

Comment: Seems like you call it twice then. Try inserting a Debug line as shown in the answer.

Comment: I tried to insert the Debug line, but I still receive the same error?

Comment: Yes, but what did the output tell? Press **Ctrl+G**.

Comment: If by output you mean the text in the immediate part, there it shows:
> False         bedrijf_project = 'Fundashon Mariadal'
> False         bedrijf_project = 'BECS'

Comment: These seem fine, so the error is most likely causes by something else.